# Trigger JS function only on weekends?

Tags: javascript, function, date

I want to create a function which only triggers on weekends (saturdays and sundays).

See my [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jm25kmu8/).

Maybe I could use the following code somewhow:

```
var d = new Date(); 
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

Comment: `if (currentDay == 'Saturday' || currentDay == 'Sunday') { }`

Comment: I accidentally asked the wrong question (sry), I need it to run on all days except weekends, saturdays and sundays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final code which works out best for me.

```
<script>
$("strong:contains('Beställ innan kl 16.00')").attr("id", "countdown").delay(1000);
    function ShowTime() {
      var now = new Date();
      var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

      now.setHours(now.getHours() + (offset+1));
      if (now.getHours() < 16) {
        var hrs = 15-now.getHours();
        var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
        var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
        if (hrs < 10) hrs = "0" + hrs;
        if (mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;
        if (secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;
        timeLeft = 'Beställ inom <span style="color: #ff713d; font-size: larger">' +hrs+'t '+mins+'m '+secs+'s</span>';
        $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
        $("span:contains('så skickas din beställning samma vardag')").html("<br />och varan skickas idag.")
      }
    }


var day = new Date().getDay(); 
if (day != 0 && day != 6){
  setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
var d = new Date(); 
if (curday == 'Saturday' || curday == 'Sunday') { 
  var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
      weekday[1] = "Monday";
      weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
      weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
      weekday[4] = "Thursday";
      weekday[5] = "Friday";
      weekday[6] = "Saturday";

      var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Actually there is nothing to display on output window.